# CosmosDb to AppService VNet integration

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, azure-cosmosdb, azure-virtual-network

I have Azure Cosmos Db hosted in the UK South region.

In Uk West, I have hosted App Service.

Cosmos Db is integrated with Uk West Vnet on Subnet A.

App Service is in the same VNet on the same subnet.

When I try to connect from App Service to Cosmos,
I'm getting - *No such host is known.*

Is there any extra configuration needed if I try to integrate resources hosted in different regions?

Comment: I assume you want the traffic to be private. Have you created a Private Endpoint for your CosmosDB instance ? Referring to https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/how-to-configure-private-endpoints

Comment: Yes, i have a private endpoint pointing to CosmosDb within Vnet that I'm integrated with.

Comment: Have you enabled Route All to force the traffic to go through the VNet ? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/configure-vnet-integration-routing
And do you have a Private DNS Zone with a record for the private endpoint to the CosmosDB instance ?

Answer (score 1):

To make it works:

- Create a private endpoint on Cosmos DB and UK West VNet.
- Integrate private endpoint with a private DNS zone (privatelink.documents.azure.com)

Answer (score 0):

It is worthy to mention that you have to link your private DNS zone into your vNet as well.